# Correct way to display an img fallback

Tags: html, media-queries, fallback

Premise: I have done a lot of research on how `img` and `source` tags work, but every single article only superficially deals with the attributes of these tags.

I need to make sure that if the browser does not support the image format (eg `.wepb`, but it can be `.raw` or `.nef`), or the path/url is wrong, there is a correct fallback to a `.jpg`, then to the `alt`. I thought of these two solutions:

```html
<!-- First solution -->
<img src="foo.jpg" alt="foo"
    srcset="foo.webp 1x">
```

```html
<!-- Second solution -->
<picture>
    <source srcset="bar.webp">
    <img src="bar.jpg" alt="bar">
</picture>
```

Neither of them works, in fact if the file is not found, or if I try with unsupported extensions, there is no fallback on `src`, but the `alt` is triggered instead.

Comment: Do not suppose there is such option(?) - alt should work for text browsers, disabled images, screen readers or additional info on mouse over...

Comment: Does this solve your problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980855/inputting-a-default-image-in-case-the-src-attribute-of-an-html-img-is-not-vali

Comment: I'd say that the `onerror()` handler could be a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231187/handling-multiple-image-fallbacks-in-javascript

Comment: Perhaps I naively omitted that I would like to fix the "problem" using pure HTML5
edit: I am also taking a look at the proposed solutions to understand where the root of the problem may be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Every single article only superficially deals with the attributes of `img` and `source`.

### For image filetype fallbacks try the type attribute on your `<source>` elements:

```html
<picture>
    <source srcset="bar.webp" type="image/webp">
    <img src="bar.jpg" alt="bar">
</picture>
```

In this example, the user agent will choose the first source that has a type attribute with a supported MIME type. If the user agent supports WebP images, the first source element will be chosen. If not, the img element will be chosen.

[Read more in the HTML Specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#introduction-3:image-format-based-selection)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I've been trying to understand!